# File and folder count

Tags: powershell

There is a folder on the remote server which has various subfolders in it. It is completely nested. I would like to:

1. Prepare an HTML report which contains folder name.
2. For every folder it should also record the file count.
3. The code needs to append the HTML file which is already created.
4. Columns required: Folder name, Folder Path, File Count

Below is the code snippet which is part of my main script. I am fairly new to PowerShell.

Can some one please help?

```
$server_dir = "D:\Data\Inbox"
$does_dir_e = (Test-Path $server_dir)

if($does_dir_e)
{
       $fso = New-Object -com "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
        $f = $fso.GetFolder($server_dir)

    foreach($folder in $f.subfolders)
    {

       $fcount = $((Get-ChildItem $folder.Path).count)
       $fname = $folder.name | Convertto-HTML -Fragment  >> C:\Temp\Server.html

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? I haven't used the HTML cmdlet before, so be aware it's ugly : )

```
$server_dir = 'D:\Data\Inbox'

if(Test-Path $server_dir)
{
       $folders = Get-ChildItem $server_dir -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer}
       $output = @()

    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {
       $fname = $folder.Name
       $fpath = $folder.FullName
       $fcount = Get-ChildItem $fpath | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Measure-Object | Select-Object -Expand Count
       $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{FolderName = $fname; FolderPath = $fpath; FileCount = $fcount}
       $output += $obj

    }
       #Output to HTML
       $output | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment >> 'C:\Temp\Server.html'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is has helped me in learning new ways of scripting.

Comment: Hello is it possible to get the heading of the column appear only once. As it seems due to the for loop, the column heading (Folder Name, Folder path and File Count) seems to be appearing for every item. Thanks

Comment: $server_dir = 'D:\SMS\Inboxes\auth'

if(Test-Path $server_dir)
{
       $folders = Get-ChildItem $server_dir -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer}

    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {
       <#$fname = $folder.Name#>
       $fpath = $folder.FullName
       $fcount = (Get-ChildItem $fpath | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Count
       $f_result = @{'FolderPath' = $fpath;
                    'FileCount' = $fcount}
      New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $f_result
    
    }
    ConvertTo-Html @f_result | Out-File 'C:\Temp\Server.html'

Comment: ConvertTo-Html : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FileCount'.
At line:17 char:19
+     ConvertTo-Html <<<<  @f_result | Out-File 'C:\Temp\Server.html'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-Html], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToHtmlCommand

Comment: sry. it's a PS 3.0 feature i guess (wrapping the code in paranthese and using .count). Fixing it now. EDIT: adding the header fix now too(collecting to array before printing). don't have PS here atm so please tell me if it doesn't work :)

Comment: Its on PS 2.0. Sry to say, the output is still the same. Thanks

Comment: Kk. I'll fix it later today if it's okey. I'm too used to 3.0 :p

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually say what isn't working for you, but the following script should get you started.

The outer loop recurses through the folders (PSIsContainer) means it is a folder.
The inner loop counts the number of files in each folder using measure-object, we filter out folders from this count to give us just the file count.

```
$path = "D:\Data\Inbox"

# Enumerate the given path recursively
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | %{

    # Add a user-defined custom member with a value of the filecount this
    # time not recursively (using measure object)
    $_ | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name FileCount -value (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname | 
        Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
        Measure-Object).Count

    # Output the required values
    $_ | select Name, FullName, FileCount | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
}
```